# How to add extra field data to a form field in Wtforms

Tags: python, forms, tornado, wtforms

I am trying to add extra data to a form field in wtforms.

I have to create a text field which has an associated unit with it (eg - meter/sec). How do I add the meter/sec string to the form field?

Is there any way to pass a dictionary or something to add data to the field that i can access in the template?

Comment: What do you mean by "extra data"? Provide sample code and what you would like to do.

Answer (score 1):

There is a not very well known parameter, `description=` to the [field constructor](http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/2.1/fields.html#wtforms.fields.Field.__init__). Though it purports to be for help text, the framework itself doesn't care what you put in there (and indeed doesn't use it anywhere at all, other than passing it along.)

So you could do, for example:

```
class PhysicsForm(Form):
    speed = TextField('Speed', description={'unit': 'meters/sec'})
    distance = TextField('Distance', description={'unit': 'kilometers'})
```

Then you could use it in a jinja-style template something like:

```
{{ form.speed }} <label>{{ form.speed.description.unit }}</label>
```

**footnote** There was no real reason for using a dictionary as the value of `description` - it was merely to illustrate that you can put nearly any value in there, including containers which can hold many values.